# Writing sentence using propositional variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How to write the sentence:
"You can't ride with an elevator, if you are shorter than 150 cm, except you are older than 16 years old."
using mathematics logic and propositional variables?
For exemple let propositions be defined as:
p: You can ride with an elevator
q: You are shorter than 150 cm   and
r: You are older than 16 years old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ride an elavator if you are not shorter than $150$ cm or  you are older than $16$:
$$ p\equiv \lnot q\lor r.$$

Taking the negative of both sides we get

$$\lnot p\equiv \lnot(\lnot q \lor r)\equiv q\land\lnot r.$$

which means that you cannot ride the elevator if you are shorter than $150$ cm and you are younger than $16$.

Does the above statement mean that you cannot ride the elevator if you are shorter than $150$ cm except you are older than $16$?

Yes, because $\lnot p$ is TRUE (i.e. you cannot ride the elevator) if you are shorter than $150$ cm ($q=$TRUE) and you are not older than $16$ ($\lnot r$=TRUE). If you are shorter than $150$ cm ($q$=TRUE) but you are older than $16$ ($\lnot r$=FALSE) then $\lnot p$=FALSE so you can ride the elevator. Also, if you are not shorter than $150$ cm then $q$=FALSE so $\lnot p$=FALSE meaning that you can ride the elavator. Finally, if you are older than $16$ then $\lnot r$=FALSE, which is enough to make $\lnot p$ to be false, allowing you to ride the elavator.